# Ember reverseObjects not working right

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm using Ember's [reverseObjects() method](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html#method_reverseObjects), but it's not working as expected.

I have a text input and a submit button. Without the reverseObjects method all items are added to the list sequentially, as expected. When type in new items it gets weird. For example, typing the numbers 1 through 9 where each number is an entry should show a list like this:

9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1

What I get when I use reverseObjects is:

9 7 5 3 1 2 4 6 8

What's going on here and how do I fix it?

here's my js:

Thanks!

```
var userList = [];

App.AddItemsController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        // item entry form submit
        inputSubmit: function(){
            var value = this.get('itemName');   // gets text input value
            userList.pushObject({
                name: value
            }).reverseObjects();
            document.querySelector('.js-input-add-item').value = ''; // clear input on submit
            return userList;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you push sequential numbers you reverse the array each time. So at each push then reverse it will look like:

1. 1
2. 1,2 reversed to 2,1
3. 2,1,3 reversed to 3,1,2
4. 3,1,2,4 reversed to 4,2,1,3
5. 4,2,1,3,5 reversed to 5,3,1,2,4
6. 5,3,1,2,4,6 reversed to 6,4,2,1,3,5
7. 6,4,2,1,3,5,7 reversed to 7,5,3,1,2,4,6
8. 7,5,3,1,2,4,6,8 reversed to 8,6,4,2,1,3,5,7
9. 8,6,4,2,1,3,5,7,9 reversed to 9,7,5,3,1,2,4,6,8

You might want to try:

```
function(){
    var value = this.get('itemName');
    userList.pushObject( {name: value} );
    document.querySelector('.js-input-add-item').value = '';
    return userList.slice().reverseObjects();
}
```

[.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) is used to create a shallow copy of the array; the copy of the array is then reversed (not the original) so that each time you append something to the array you are not flipping the order every time.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ng2LcLba/)

Comment: thanks! i'll give it a shot. can you explain why use slice solves the problem?